# MySQL Stored Procedure, One INSERT not functioning with different field name?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

This is quite a strange problem, so first I will post the procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `blahblahblah`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `duplicateTradeIn`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`blahblahblah` PROCEDURE `duplicateTradeIn`(duplicate_claim INT(12))
BEGIN

DECLARE valuation INT(12) DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE claim INT(12) DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE serialNumber VARCHAR(255);
DECLARE duplicates INT(12);
DECLARE i INT(12) DEFAULT 1;
DECLARE claimID INT(12);

SET @claimID = duplicate_claim;
SET @duplicates = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `duplicates`);
SET @i = 1;

WHILE @i <= @duplicates DO

    SET @serialNumber = (SELECT `serial` FROM `duplicates` WHERE id = @i);

    INSERT INTO valuations (`pID`,`boughtproduct`,`valuationType`,`valuationAmount`,`working`,`accessories`,`age`,`brand`,`qty`,`created`,`valuationStatus`)
    SELECT `pID`,`boughtproduct`,`valuationType`,`valuationAmount`,`working`,`accessories`,`age`,`brand`,`qty`,`created`,`valuationStatus`
    FROM valuations WHERE vID = (SELECT vID FROM claims WHERE cID = @claimID);

    SET @valuation = (SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID());

    INSERT INTO claims (`vID`, `pID`, `email`, `title`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `customerType`, `company`, `position`, `address1`,`address2`,`town`,`county`,`postCode`,`telephone`,`mobile`,`emailBusiness`,`emailConsumer`,`contactPost`,`contactTelephone`,`contactMobile`,`contactEmail`,`invoiceNum`,`invoiceDate`,`invoiceInc`,`reseller`,`dateOfOrder`,`heardAbout`,`salesPerson`,`method`,`cleanseCert`,`blanccoCert`,`created`,`modified`,`noInvEmailDated`,`lateRejEmailSent`,`invAddressEmailSent`,`revalueEmailSent`,`signed`,`dated`,`sessionID`,`received`,`receiptSent`,`processedDate`,`validatedDate`,`rejectedDate`,`rejectReason`,`notes`,`claimStatus`,`origin`,`invoiceexported`)
    SELECT @valuation, `pID`, `email`, `title`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `customerType`, `company`, `position`, `address1`,`address2`,`town`,`county`,`postCode`,`telephone`,`mobile`,`emailBusiness`,`emailConsumer`,`contactPost`,`contactTelephone`,`contactMobile`,`contactEmail`,`invoiceNum`,`invoiceDate`,`invoiceInc`,`reseller`,`dateOfOrder`,`heardAbout`,`salesPerson`,`method`,`cleanseCert`,`blanccoCert`,`created`,`modified`,`noInvEmailDated`,`lateRejEmailSent`,`invAddressEmailSent`,`revalueEmailSent`,`signed`,`dated`,`sessionID`,`received`,`receiptSent`,`processedDate`,`validatedDate`,`rejectedDate`,`rejectReason`,`notes`,`claimStatus`,`origin`,`invoiceexported`
    FROM claims WHERE cID = @claimID;

    SET @claim = (SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID());

    INSERT INTO documents (`claimid`,`serial`,`filename`,`filenameOrig`,`filenameTemp`,`filetype`,`filesize`)
    SELECT @claim,`serial`,`filename`,`filenameOrig`,`filenameTemp`,`filetype`,`filesize`
    FROM documents WHERE claimid = @claimID;

    INSERT INTO redemptions (`cID`,`pID`,`prID`,`bundleNo`,`serialNum`,`price`,`cashback`,`created`,`modified`,`claimStatus`)
    SELECT @claim,`pID`,`prID`,`bundleNo`,@serialNumber,`price`,`cashback`,`created`,`modified`,`claimStatus`
    FROM redemptions WHERE cID = @claimID;

    INSERT INTO tradeins (`vID`,`cID`,`valuationType`,`valuationAmount`,`working`,`accessories`,`age`,`created`,`brand`,`claimStatus`)
    SELECT @valuation,@claim,`valuationType`,`valuationAmount`,`working`,`accessories`,`age`,`created`,`brand`,`claimStatus`
    FROM tradeins WHERE cID = @claimID;

    SET @i = (@i + 1);

END WHILE;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

EDIT: Sorry!

The problem is when it tries to insert into documents (So refer to the documents table insert). If I rename the column (claimid) in the WHERE clause and INSERT to cID (by altering the table and query) it works, but otherwise it refuses to insert the new rows when it is named claimid not cID. If you have any ideas or insight into this it would be much appreciated.

To try and clarify:

Documents table with field and query as cID not claimid works.
Documents table with field and query as claimid does not insert rows.

All of the other queries seem to work fine and it only occurred to me to try cID in the documents table as that was the only difference.

Again sorry for the vagueness before and I hope the question is now clearer.

Thanks!

Comment: This is quite a strange question. You paste a whole bunch of sql with column names all over the place and then refer to "THE" column. Is this a trick question where we should guess which column you are refering to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to clear this up. It is as I stated and maybe a bug in mySQL? If there is a table with a field where the ID name differs. In this example cID and claimid then it will not recognise the second declared field claimid and not perform the query.

In order for this to work I had to revise the documents table from claimID to cID.